# Qt creator make network requests without creating a callback hell

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt-creator

So, I have this simplified code as an example for my problem:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>

void third()
{
    qInfo() << "finished everything!";
}

// will use stuff downloaded by `first()`, which will be used by `third`
void second(const std::function<void()>& cb = [] {})
{
    // this has to be called after `first()` has been called and finished

    // finished, calling callback
    cb();
}

// Will download some stuff, which will be used by `second()`
void first(const std::function<void()>& cb = [] {})
{
    // finished, calling callback
    cb();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    first([=] {
        second(third);
    });

    // or, even worse
    first([=] {
        second([=] {
            third();
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any way, that I can prevent this callback hell from happening?
I thought about making another thread, where I would call those functions, block that thread and wait for them to finish.

I am not super sure on how I would do that though. So, first of all, is there a better way to write this (maybe even without creating another thread?) and secondly, if I had to make this happen on another thread, how would I do that?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can't you use signals and slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals and slots quite naturally clean up this kind of code. For example:

```
class Downloader : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   void beginDownload() // this is your first
   {
      emit downloadFinished({});
   }
signals:
   void downloadFinished(const QByteArray& data);
};

class DataProcessorA: public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   void processData(const QByteArray& data) // this is your second
   {
      emit processingFinished({});
   }
signals:
   void processingFinished(const QDateArray& processedData);
};

class DataProcessorB: public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   void processData2(const QByteArray& data) // this is your third
   {
      emit processingFinished({});
   }
signals:
   void processingFinished(const QDateArray& processedData);
};

void myFunction()
{
   auto* downloader = new Downloader(parent);
   auto* processorA = new DataProcessorA(parent);
   auto* processorB = new DataProcessorB(parent);
   // make first call second...
   QObject::connect(downloader, &Downloader::downloadFinished, processorA, &DataProcessorA::processData);
   // make second call third...
   QObject::connect(processorA , &DataProcessorA::processingFinished, processorB, &DataProcessorB::processData);
}
```

This can work even if the download is executed on a separate thread because Qt's signals/slots can work between threads. The data in the signal will be copied to the receiving thread. Ref: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

There is a bit of boilerplate with all the `QObject` stuff, but this should allow you to write each piece in isolation and then be able to flexibly connect the individual pieces using `QObject::connect`.